# InvocationTargetException while trying to add variables to a new object

Tags: java, processing, osc

I am trying to send two variables from one sketch to another, using the oscP5 library for processing.
The message I am sending is created like this:

```
 OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/test");
 myMessage.add(title);
 myMessage.add("Zeit");
 oscP5.send(myMessage, remoteLocation);
```

In the second sketch, I receive the data like that:

```
 void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
   if(theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/test")) {
     String title = theOscMessage.get(0).stringValue();
     String layoutType = theOscMessage.get(1).stringValue();

     addToQueue(title, layoutType);
   }
 }
```

And here my simplified addToQueue function:

```
 void addToQueue(String title, String layoutType) {
   if(!existsInQueues(title)) {
     upcomingHeadlines.add(new Headline(title, printAxis, scrollSpeed, layoutType));
   } 
 }
```

Every time I start the sketches, I get the error:

> ERROR @ OscP5 ERROR. an error occured while forwarding an OscMessage to a method in your program. please check your code for any possible errors that might occur in the method where incoming OscMessages are parsed e.g. check for casting errors, possible nullpointers, array overflows ... .
>   method in charge : oscEvent  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I have been able to track the problem down to the `layoutType`-Variable. If I change

```
  String layoutType = theOscMessage.get(1).stringValue();
```

to

```
  String layoutType = "Zeit";
```

no error occurs.
That is quite confusing, because both versions should have the same result.
The error message does not help me in any way.

---

### Edit

I have compared the two possible variables like that:

```
String layoutType = theOscMessage.get(1).stringValue();
String layoutTypeB = "Zeit";
if(layoutType.equals(layoutTypeB)) println("Same String!");
```

Since gets printed to the console, both have to be the same … I really do not know where to search for an error anymore.

---

### Edit 2

I have wrapped my second sketch in `try {...} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}` like that:

```
void oscEvent(OscMessage theOscMessage) {
  try {  
    if(theOscMessage.checkAddrPattern("/test")) {
      if(debug && debugFeed) println("Received message from other sketch.");

      String title = theOscMessage.get(0).stringValue();
      String layoutTypeO = (String)theOscMessage.get(1).stringValue();
      String layoutType = "Zeit";
      if(debug && debugTemp) {
        if(layoutType.equals(layoutTypeO)) println("IS DOCH GLEICH!");
      }
      if(debug && debugFeed) println("Parsed Information.");
      if(debug && debugFeed) println("-----");
      addToQueue(title, layoutTypeO);
    }
  } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

That gives me this error as result:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0  
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)  
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)  
    at printer$Headline.useLayout(printer.java:260)  
    at printer$Headline.<init>(printer.java:188)  
    at printer.addToQueue(printer.java:407)  
    at printer.oscEvent(printer.java:395)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)  
    at oscP5.OscP5.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at oscP5.OscP5.callMethod(Unknown Source)  
    at oscP5.OscP5.process(Unknown Source)  
    at oscP5.OscNetManager.process(Unknown Source)  
    at netP5.AbstractUdpServer.run(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

---

### Edit 4

Constructor for my `Headline`-Class:

```
class Headline {

  //Define Variables
  Layout layout;
  String title, lastHeadline;
  float yPos, speed;
  float transparency = 255;
  boolean fullyPrinted = false;
  int boundingBoxHeight;

  // Initialize Class Function
  Headline(String t, float y, float s, String lay) {
    title = t;
    yPos = y;
    speed = s;
    layout = useLayout(lay);
    boundingBoxHeight = calculateTextHeight(title);
  }
```

You might want to know about `useLayout()` too, so here it is:

```
Layout useLayout(String name) {
    ArrayList layoutVariants = new ArrayList<Layout>();
    int existingLayouts = layouts.size();
    Layout chosenLayout;

    for(int i = 0; i < existingLayouts; i++) {
      Layout currentLayout = (Layout)layouts.get(i);
      if(currentLayout.layoutType == name) {
        layoutVariants.add(currentLayout);
      }
    }

    if(layoutVariants != null) {
      int rand = (int)(Math.random() * layoutVariants.size());
      chosenLayout = (Layout)layoutVariants.get(rand);
    } else {
      chosenLayout = (Layout)layouts.get((int)(Math.random() * existingLayouts)); 
    }
  return chosenLayout;
}
```

Comment: What does the `getCause()` method of the `InvocationTargetException` return?

Comment: How do I get that? I am new to java, sorry.

Comment: try to surround your code with `try {...} catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}` to see whether the exception originates in your code.

Comment: Hi @SillyFreak, I have tried that out. I have posted the result to my original post under edit2. I have no clue what the error tells me. Could you help me out?

Comment: The error would seem to be in an inner class `Headline` within your `printer` class.   Can you please edit your question to include this method, as well as the constructor for the `Headline` class?

Comment: @LukeWoodward I have not created any class named printer, but it is the name of the document. I added the constructor of my `Headline`-Class to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code, and both of them are in your `useLayout` method.

The first problem is that you are not comparing `Strings`s correctly on this line:

```
    if(currentLayout.layoutType == name) {
```

`name` is a `String`, and I assume `currentLayout.layoutType` is too.  Two `String`s that are equal but not the same will not compare equal under `==`.  As a result of this, your `layoutVariants` list will quite probably be empty at the end of the `for` loop.

This line should read:

```
    if(currentLayout.layoutType.equals(name)) {
```

[See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

The second problem is that you don't correctly handle the case that the `layoutVariants` list is empty.  The problem is on this line:

```
    if(layoutVariants != null) {
```

`layoutVariants` will never be null, so the `else` branch of this `if` statement will never execute.  Because `layoutVariants.size()` will be zero, `rand` will always be zero.   Trying to get the element at index 0 in an empty ArrayList will give you precisely the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you are seeing.

I imagine you want the `else` block to execute if the layout name given isn't recognised, in other words, if the `layoutVariants` list is *empty*, rather than null.  In that case, change this line to

```
    if(!layoutVariants.isEmpty()) {
```

Note the `!` (not-operator) before `layoutVariants`.  You want the code under the `if` statement to run if the `layoutVariants` element is *not* empty.

**EDIT** in response to your comments:  a `null` ArrayList is very much not the same as an empty one.  `null` is a special value meaning that the variable doesn't have an object of a given type.

Let's try a real-world analogy: a shopping bag.  If you have an empty bag, or no bag at all, then you have no shopping either way.  However, you can put things into an empty bag, and count how many items it contains, for example.  If you don't have a bag, then it doesn't make sense to put an item in it, as there's no bag to put the item into.  `null` represents the case where you don't have a bag.

Similarly, a `String` is a collection of characters, and the collection of characters can exist even if it doesn't contain any characters.

`isEmpty()` can be used for [any collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty()), and, if you're using Java 6 or later, [Strings as well](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()).  Off the top of my head I can't name any other classes that have an `isEmpty` method.  You'll just have to consult the documentation for these classes to find out.

I've not worked with Processing much, but I am aware that Processing is built on Java, so I would expect any standard Java method to work.  Also, I wouldn't worry about 'clearing' a variable: the JVM is generally very good at clearing up after you.  There's certainly nothing I can see wrong with your code in this respect.

**EDIT 2** in response to your further comment: `ArrayList arr;` declares a variable of type `ArrayList`.  However, the variable `arr` is *uninitialized*: it does not have a value (not even `null`) and it is an error to try to read the value of this variable before you have assigned a value to it:

```
ArrayList arr;
System.out.println(arr);     // compiler error: arr might not have been initialised.
```

Assign `null` and the code then compiles:

```
ArrayList arr = null;
System.out.println(arr);     // prints 'null'.
```

It's not often you need to declare a variable and not give it a name, but one common case is where you want to assign different values to the same variable on both sides of an `if` statement.  The following code doesn't compile:

```
int y = getMeSomeInteger();   // assume this function exists
if (y == 4) {
    int x = 2;
} else {
    int x = 5;
}
System.out.println(x);        // compiler error: cannot find symbol x
```

The reason it doesn't compile is that each variable `x` is only available within the braces `{` and `}` that contain it.  At the bottom, neither variable `x` is available and so you get a compiler error.

We need to declare `x` further up.  We could instead write the following;

```
int y = getMeSomeInteger();   // assume this function exists
int x = 0;
if (y == 4) {
    x = 2;
} else {
    x = 5;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

This code compiles and runs, but the value `0` initially assigned to `x` is never used.  There isn't a lot of point in doing this, and we can get rid of this unused value by declaring the variable but not immediately giving it a value.

```
int y = getMeSomeInteger();   // assume this function exists
int x;
if (y == 4) {
    x = 2;
} else {
    x = 5;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. Could you give me a bit more insight to `.isEmpty()`?  I thought an empty string or ArrayList would be `null`. Where is the difference? And can `.isEmpty()` be used for ArrayLists and variables? Also how to clear a variable correctly?  I have not found anything about `.isEmpty()` in the Processing Reference.

Comment: Yes, that is a very good explanation. I have one last question though: `ArrayList arr;` would be `null`, until I fill it with `arr = new ArrayList();` which would be an empty array until i add content like `arr.add(content);`. Is that right?

Comment: @Afterlame: no, sadly that's not quite right. See my updated answer.